# Let $X: U(0,1)$ and when $X=x$ then $Y:U(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{2x}{3})$ uniform distribution. Find the density function of $Y$ and $EY$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X: U(0,1)$ and when $X=x$ then $Y:U(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{2x}{3})$ uniform distribution. Find the density function of $Y$ and $EY$

I don't know if it would be presumptuousness to say that $Y: (0, \frac{2}{3})$ so I wouldn't know how to continue the example, any thoughts on how to solve such a problem?

Comment: $Y$ is supported over $(0;2/3)$ but its not uniformly distributed there.  It might help visualize things if you sketch a graph of the joint support.  It's an obtuse triangle that will be denser closer to the apex at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started

We have $X\;\sim\;\mathcal U(0;1)$ and $Y\rvert_{X=x}\;\sim\;\mathcal U(x/2;2x/3)$

So this means: $$\begin{align}
f_X(x) &= \mathbf 1_{\{0\leq x\leq 1\}}
\\[2ex]f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) & = \dfrac{6}{x}\;\mathbf 1_{\{x/2\leq y\leq 2x/3\},\{0\leq x\leq 1\}}
\\[1ex] &= \dfrac{6}{x}\;\mathbf 1_{\{0\leq x\leq 1\},\{3y/2\leq x \leq 2y\},\{0\leq y \leq 2/3\}} \end{align}$$

Then we can find the density function of $Y$: $$\begin{align}f_Y(y) & =\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \int_{\max(0,3y/2)}^{\min(1,2y)} \frac 6 x\operatorname dx \; \mathbf 1_{0\leq y \leq 2/3}
\\[1ex] & = \int_{3y/2}^{2y} \frac 6 x\operatorname dx \; \mathbf 1_{0\leq y \leq 1/2}+\int_{3y/2}^{1} \frac 6 x\operatorname dx \; \mathbf 1_{1/2\lt y \leq 2/3}
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

---

**Note** We can also get the expectation of $Y$ directly without needing to find the density of $Y$. $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(Y) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1\int_{x/2}^{2x/3} y\cdot \frac {6} x\;\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Comment: May I just ask what this 1 signifies? (bolded ?)

Comment: @JimLowe it is an **indicator function**, which is a piecewise function which has value of one when the subscript is true, and zero elsewhere. $$\mathbf 1_{a<x<b}=\begin{cases}1 & : a<x<b \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Or do I just find: $ \int_{3y/2}^{2y} \frac 6 x dx $ and write beside it $y \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: I understand everything now, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JimLowe $Y$ for a given $X=x$ ( where $x\in(0;1)$ ) is uniformly distributed over $(x/2; 2x/3)$ so its conditional density is $\frac{1}{2x/3-x/2}$, which is $6/x$.  We add the indicator function to indicate the supported values of the arguments, $x, y$.